# Javascript Find and Replace Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing, bbcode

I am wanting to add my own bbcodes to a wygiwys bbcode editor. The issue I am having is that it can find the bbcode and change to html, but it cant the other way. I am not used to writing safe strings in javascript so was hoping someone could point the problem out to me.

HTML to BBcode Line

```
rep(/<(div style=\"background-color:\s[^<>]*?#fff; padding: 8px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;\"|b)(\s[^<>]*)?>/gi,"[boxone]");
rep(/<\/(div|b)>/gi, "[/boxone]");
```

BBcode to HTML line (This one Works)

```
rep(/\[boxone\]/gi,"<div style=\"background-color: #fff; padding: 8px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;\">");
rep(/\[\/boxone\]/gi,"</div>");
```

The idea is to change `[boxone] Content [/boxone]` to

```
<div style="background-color: #fff; padding: 8px; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #EAEAEA;">$1</div>
```

and visaversa.

Aply help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use regular expressions, as you're looking for specific strings. A simple string replace should do the job (just make sure you escape characters where needed).

I don't know what language you use, but wouldn't this simply work:

```
rep('[/boxone]','</div>');
```

Comment: well im just trying to modify a wysiwyg bbcode editor. Javascript n html